# Select Xml value based on parent value in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, .net-core

I am trying to select a xml value by matching on the value of the id tag before it

```
<unit>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>foo</name>
</unit>
<unit>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>bar</name>
</unit>
```

Given my id is 2 in the above scenario I would like to get the value 'bar'.

Any advice or library suggestions to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use LINQ to XML for this:

- Find the element you want
- Use its `Parent` property to get to the `unit`
- Use the `Element` method to get the `name`

Sample code:

```cs
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var id = doc.Descendants("id").Where(id => id.Value == "2").SingleOrDefault();
if (id is null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No such ID");
    return;
}
else
{
    var unit = id.Parent;
    var nameElement = unit?.Element("name");
    if (nameElement is null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No name element");
        return;
    }
    string name = nameElement.Value;

    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {name}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simple one liner using Linq-to-XML, after loading your file into `XDocument`.

```cs
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
// alternatively XDocument.Parse

var name = doc.Elements("unit")
    .FirstOrDefault(unit => unit.Element("id")?.Value == "2")
    .Element("name")?.Value;
```